# PHP 7.1 not recognizing the PHP5.6+ syntax `use function`

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP website running on Apache and PHP 7.1.
The application is running well on my PC, when I deploy to the server I get the following error:

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or \\\\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR)
```

When I looked into the location the error is happening at, it was a PHP5.6+ syntax as I understood:

```
use function ...;
```

When I run `php --version` or `which php` it shows it is PHP 7.1.
Is there a setting that configures php to allow syntax above certain version?

EDIT:
phpinfo() is reporting PHP 5.5.9
I guess what I need is help on how to set Apache to use the default PHP version which is 7.1 in case of my server.

Comment: Are you sure your Apache uses the save php version as your web server's cli? Put `phpinfo();exit;` into the code and show us the results.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone `use function` is a valid [use statement](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) in PHP.

Comment: phpinfo is reporting PHP version 5.5.9, I guess I need to set apache to use the default PHP which is 7.1 in this case. I will edit the question

Comment: @LawrenceCherone If we don't know about the imported function then how did you certainly said *it's complaining because of `function`*?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, as I said before the same code is running on my PC because my PC is correctly running PHP 7.1. So the problem is all related to the PHP version not the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to disable the module PHP 5 and enable 7.1 for apache:

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php7.1
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score -2):

```
use keywork will support all version of php. i think your function declaration error. 
you can use below example and correct your function
**use** can only be used with anonymous functions. Using it with named functions 
 gives a syntax error.

 <?
function counter($start) {
  $value = $start;

 return function() use (&$value) {
   return $value++;
 };
```

}

```
 $counter = counter(6);

echo $counter() . "\n";
echo $counter() . "\n";
```